# Is it possible to get Cluster -> Availability Group Instance Node Map via WMI?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wmi, wmi-query, failovercluster

I wish to enumerate all the instances within a SQL Server Always On Availability Group.

There is a [Dynamic Management View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710076.aspx) within SQL Sever which provides this, but you need to be connected to a relevant instance to query this view.

Also, I can see in the registry for a node on the cluster that there is the mapping that I wish to get: `HKLM\Cluster\Resources\{cluster_guid}\SqlInstToNodeMap`

There is a [WMI class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371464(v=vs.85).aspx) that can enumerate all Availability Groups on the cluster, but I cannot see how (even by examining the PrivateProperties object) I can enumerate the SQL Instance to Cluster Node map through WMI - does anyone know if this is possible, or can provide a mechanism that doesn't require looking at the registry or querying SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but you could get it using the SMO classes?

```
Server srv = new Server("instance_name")
```

You can the access the [AvailabilityReplics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929148(v=sql.120).aspx) property of each [AvailabilityGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.availabilitygroup(v=sql.120).aspx) in the [AvailabilityGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff930513(v=sql.120).aspx) collection to get the replica nodes, something like (untested)

```
Server srv = new Server("instance_name")
foreach(AvialbilityGroup grp in srv.AvailabilityGroups)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Found group {0} on instance {1}", grp.Name, srv.InstanceName);
  Console.WriteLine("  Replicas:");
  foreach(AvailabilityReplica replica in grp.AvailabilityReplicas)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("  Replica Name: {0}, Cluster Name: {1}", replica.Name, repica.Parent.Parent.ClusterName)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. Whilst this is useful, it is not what I want as I don't want to query SQL Server directly, rather get a list of the instances from the cluster's AG resource via some sort of API